# Circular Progress Bar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, progress

Does anyone know how to plot the circular progress bar in MATLAB. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: yes, but it's undocumented: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/animated-busy-spinning-icon

Comment: you could also use this FEX submission http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53383-cprogress